# I have a question regarding Android notification batch specifications

Tags: android, push-notification

According to the official version, since 8.0 (API level 26), when there is a notification, the notification batch appears on the launcher icon, and a long press on the app icon will show the notification.

However, I believe that the launcher is dependent on the device model and therefore does not always show up, are there any exceptions?

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges?hl=ja

No attempt was made due to questions regarding specifications.
We are checking because it needs to be mentioned in the product FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the launcher is the device pre-included default launcher app, it guarantees to show a notification badge.
Because it is [Android compatibility specification](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd?hl=en#3_8_user_interface_compatibility).
The specification is as follows.

> If device implementations include a default launcher app that shows badges for the app icons,
> they MUST respect the NotificationChannel.setShowBadge() API method. In other words, show a visual affordance associated with the app icon if the value is set as true, and do not show any app icon badging scheme when all of the app's notification channels have set the value as false.

But When it comes to third-party applications, it is not guaranteed.
The specification only recommends the support of notification badge.
As indicated in the [setNumber](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setNumber(int)) and [setBadgeIconType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setBadgeIconType%28int%29) documentation, there may be third-party applications that disregard the notification badge.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in contacting you.
Thank you for your response. It was very helpful.